# Get the area under a ROC curve in python pyod?

Tags: python, knn, roc, auc

I have data for 5,000 observations. I split the dataset in two: the variables (`X_train`) and the labeled target (`y_train`). I am using `pyod` because it seems to be the most popular Python library for anomaly detection.

I fit the model to the data with the following code:

```py
from pyod.models.knn import KNN
from pyod.utils import evaluate_print

clf = KNN(n_neighbors=10, method='mean', metric='euclidean')
clf.fit(X_train)
scores = clf.decision_scores_
```

The model is now fitted and I have the probability of an observation being an outlier stored in `scores`. I manually calculated the area under the ROC curve and it returned 0.69.

I noticed this is the same result when using:

```py
evaluate_print('KNN with k=10', y=y_train, y_pred=scores)
```

Which returns: `KNN with k=10 ROC:0.69, precision @ rank n:0.1618`.

**I want to know if there is a specific function in `pyod` which would return only the 0.69.**

Comment: I do not know `pyod` but ``sklearn` has the `roc_auc_score` or `auc` which does that job. It is very easy to use and I imagine it is a line or two to work with your project

Comment: @CutePoison It worked! Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know pyod but `sklearn` has the roc_auc_score or `auc` which does that job. It is very easy to use and I imagine it is a line or two to work with your project.

```py
from sklearn import metrics

fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true=y_train, y_score=scores)
auc.append(metrics.auc(fpr, tpr))
```

Answer (score 0):

The pyod package itself computes ROC from sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score. You can see that in Benchmark.ipynb in notebooks folder of the pyod repository. So to get only the ROC please use this:
`from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score`

`roc = round(roc_auc_score(y_test, test_scores))`